# How to create structured help screens with formatting in Android

Tags: android, xml

I wish to add some help screens to my Android app.  I have seen these in other apps where the help screen is presented in the form of an outline and if you click on a subject heading in the outline it expands to the next level of detail.

I am currently using string resources in my strings.xml to house my help information.  However, it is flat with no structure.  I would think there would be xml formatting tokens that would indicate subject headings and such but I am having a hard time finding documentation on this.  Can anyone provide a pointer?

Answer (score 0):

The API Demos app on some of the emulators, e.g., any 2.2 emulator, includes an example of an expandable list.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html

If that's not you were looking for, are you able to point to an example that does something more similar to what you're after?

Comment: Well, this would be better than nothing.  However, it seems a little specialized for documentation.  For instance, it would allow only one level of detail under a subject heading.  I am more looking for an outline approach that would allow any number of levels of branching like many types of online documentation.

Comment: The Astro File Manager has nice help screens.  Certain words are links to more detail or other sections of the documentation.  This is not exactly what I was thinking of but it would be a nice alternative.  Does anybody know how this was done?